# Pandas cumsum from the second element of each group

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following. The rightmost column is my desired column:

```
Group   Value   Target_CumSum   
1        3         0     
1        2         2  
1        5         7
1        4         11
2        1         0
2        5         5
2        9         14
2        3         17
```

How do I perform the `cumsum()` from the second element of each group as opposed to the very first one?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'Value': [3,2,5,4,1,5,9,3], 'Target_CumSum': [0,2,7,11,0,5,14,17]})
#df['MyCumSum']= df.groupby(['Group'])['Value'].cumsum()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
g=df.groupby('Group').Value
g.cumsum()-g.transform('first')
Out[597]: 
0     0
1     2
2     7
3    11
4     0
5     5
6    14
7    17
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont think theres a built in function for that. so you would have to make a custom function and apply it. hope it helps.

```
def custom_cumsum (X):

    X[1:] =  np.cumsum(X[1:])
    X.iloc[0] = 0

    return X

df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].apply(custom_cumsum)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do I need `import numpy as np` before I can use `np.cumsum`?

Comment: @gibbz00 Actually, pandas automatically imports numpy, so you can use `pd.np.cumsum` if you don't want to import it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to offer another solution:

```
df['Value'].where(df['Group'].duplicated(), 0).groupby(df.Group).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0     0
1     2
2     7
3    11
4     0
5     5
6    14
7    17
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer Scott. Can you please elaborate a little on whats going on in that one line of code?

Comment: @gibbz00 First we, select the "Value" column from the dataframe, then we use the "Group" column and `duplicated` function to determine which rows are duplicates, ie not the first for in the group.  Then we, mask the first row with zero using the `where` function.  Lastly, we group the 'Value' series with zero replace for the first row in a group using the 'Group' column and cumsum.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [87]: df.groupby(['Group']).apply(lambda x: x['Value'].shift(-1).cumsum().shift().fillna(0))
Out[87]:
Group
1      0     0.0
       1     2.0
       2     7.0
       3    11.0
2      4     0.0
       5     5.0
       6    14.0
       7    17.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```